# Script element is different in dev tools when opened with VS Code Live Server vs when opened with Mousepad

Tags: javascript, console

Trying to find the output of 'x' in console, when opened with mousepad it returns the value '1' but when ran with VS Code Live Server Extender it returns

Uncaught ReferenceError: output is not defined
at :1:1

This is what i'm trying to run

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Function scope example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    let x = 1;

    function a() {
      let y = 2;
    }

    function b() {
      let z = 3;
    }

    function output(value) {
      const para = document.createElement('p');
      document.body.appendChild(para);
      para.textContent = 'Value: ' + value;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works fine whe used with mousepad but VS Code rewrites my script or something. Why?

Comment: What is calling the function output?

Comment: Me, I'm getting my feet wet with JS and experimenting with scope. Ill enter output(x) into the console expecting the answer 1 but with VS Code it wont do the math